# How to check if Azure AD User exist?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a script that allows to copy Azure AD groups from one user to another. The issue I have is the fact that I can't validate if the source or target user exists. Can you help me with this?

```
# Azure AD sign-in
Connect-AzureAD

# enter UPN of the first user
$user1 = Read-host "Enter username to copy from: "

# enter UPN of the second user
$user2  = Read-host "Enter username to copy to: " 

# Get ObjectId based on username of user to copy from and user to copy to
$user1Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user1
$user2Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user2


#Get the Source and Target users
$SourceUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter { UserPrincipalName -eq $user1 }
$TargetUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter { UserPrincipalName -eq $user2 }


$membershipGroups1 = Get-AzureADUserMembership -All $true -ObjectId $user1Obj.ObjectId
$membershipGroups2 = Get-AzureADUserMembership -All $true -ObjectId $user2Obj.ObjectId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'DisplayName'

If($Null -ne $SourceUser -and $Null -ne $TargetUser)
{

foreach ($group in $membershipGroups) 
{
    if ($group.DisplayName -notin $membershipGroups2) { 
        Write-Host "[!] - Adding" $user2Obj.UserPrincipalName " to " $group.DisplayName '... ' -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user2Obj.ObjectId
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "User is already memberof $($group.Displayname)" -ForegroundColor 'Green'
    }

        $date = get-date -format g
        Write-Host "[$date] : Source or Target user is invalid!" -ForegroundColor Red
       }
}
Write-Host "Done!"
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you're having a problem, `Get-AzureADUser` will return an error if the user doesn't exist

Comment: the write-host part at the end doesnt work. I dont know what im doing wrong

Write-Host "[$date] : Source or Target user is invalid!" -ForegroundColor Red

Comment: shouldn't that be in your `else` block?

Comment: there is one closing bracket to much. your code can not work. Even when you remove the bracket the current code will always print [$date] : Source or Target user is invalid! for each group. there is no condition to check anything before writing this message

Comment: There's an issue with the syntax used when running `Get-AzureADUser` for `$SourceUser` and `$TargetUser`, but ignoring that, due to the `if-else` conditions, the `Write-Host` line wouldn't even run if the user doesn't exist. There should be an `else` clause in the outer `if-else` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewritten as explained in my comment. Also removed the entire `$SourceUser` and `$TargetUser` references since I don't see the purpose for those.

```
# Azure AD sign-in
Connect-AzureAD

# enter UPN of the first user
$user1 = Read-host "Enter username to copy from: "

# enter UPN of the second user
$user2  = Read-host "Enter username to copy to: " 

# Get ObjectId based on username of user to copy from and user to copy to
$user1Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user1
$user2Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user2

$membershipGroups1 = Get-AzureADUserMembership -All $true -ObjectId $user1Obj.ObjectId
$membershipGroups2 = Get-AzureADUserMembership -All $true -ObjectId $user2Obj.ObjectId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'DisplayName'

If($Null -ne $user1Obj -and $Null -ne $user2Obj)
{

    foreach ($group in $membershipGroups) 
    {
        if ($group.DisplayName -notin $membershipGroups2) { 
            Write-Host "[!] - Adding" $user2Obj.UserPrincipalName " to " $group.DisplayName '... ' -ForegroundColor Yellow
           # Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user2Obj.ObjectId
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "User is already memberof $($group.Displayname)" -ForegroundColor 'Green'
        }
    }
}
else {
    $date = get-date -format g
    Write-Host "[$date] : Source or Target user is invalid!" -ForegroundColor Red
}
Write-Host "Done!"
```

You might also try using a `try-catch` block earlier in the script

```
try {
    $user1Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user1
    $user2Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user2
}
catch {
    $date = get-date -format g
    Write-Host "[$date] : Source or Target user is invalid!" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went this way and it works fine. Thanks for all your answers

```
# Azure AD sign-in
  Connect-AzureAD

# enter UPN of the first user
$user1 = Read-host "Enter username to copy from: "

# enter UPN of the second user
$user2  = Read-host "Enter username to copy to: " 

# Get-AzureADUserMembership
$membershipGroups1 = Get-AzureADUserMembership -All $true -ObjectId $user1Obj.ObjectId
$membershipGroups2 = Get-AzureADUserMembership -All $true -ObjectId $user2Obj.ObjectId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'DisplayName'


try {

# Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID to validate if the user exists
$user1Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user1
$user2Obj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $user2

foreach ($group in $membershipGroups1) 
{
    if ($group.DisplayName -notin $membershipGroups2) { 
        $date = get-date -format g
        Write-Host "[!] - Adding" $user2Obj.UserPrincipalName " to " $group.DisplayName '... ' -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user2Obj.ObjectId
    }
    else {
        $date = get-date -format g
        Write-Host "User is already memberof $($group.Displayname)" -ForegroundColor 'Red'

    }
  }
}
   catch {
    $date = get-date -format g
    Write-Host "[$date] : Source or Target user is invalid!" -ForegroundColor Red
 }

Write-Host "Done!"
```